# Eager Loading by Setting Variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

Sorry in advance for this incredibly simple question, but what is the best way to set a variable while also checking a condition. For example, I have:

```
@friends = []
@user.facebook_friends.each do |key,value|
  if test = Authorization.includes(:user).find_by_uid(key) != nil
    @friends << {"name" => test.user.name, "facebook_image_url" => test.user.facebook_image_url}
  end
end
```

I am trying to pull in the user records when I pull in the authorization record, so as to minimize my database queries. I know that I can't write

```
test = Authorization.includes(:user).find_by_uid(key) != nil
```

in order to set the test variable. What is the best way to write this code so that it is functional?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need parens:

```
(test = Authorization.includes(:user).find_by_uid(key)) != nil
```

Also here is a more rails way to do it:

```
unless (test = Authorization.includes(:user).find_by_uid(key)).nil?
    @friends << {"name" => test.user.name, "facebook_image_url" => test.user.facebook_image_url}
end
```

Comment: Wow! I thought I tried that before and it didn't work. I just tried it again and it did! Thanks for answering my dumb question.